# Why tmap invokes R device in t_map_mode("view")

Tags: r, tmap, mapview

I am trying tmap for the first time and while making some maps on "view" mode the R graphics device pops up everytime I attempt to make an interactive plot. For instance:

```
library(tmap)
library(mapview)
data(World)

# just the map
tmap_mode("view")
qtm(World)
#The map gets displayed on my browser but an R empty device gets invoked as well.
#How can I avoid the R device from popping up?
```

However, that doesn't happen when using mapview:

```
mapview(World)
```

Answer (score 0):

Digging in, the `tmap:::pre_prepare_vp()` function calls `dev.size()` [here](https://github.com/r-tmap/tmap/blob/39acf6cbe06a893487b08fb147494807274ab159/R/pre_prepare_vp.R#LL4C3-L4C3), which triggers the creation of a new device window. The function is called from [here](https://github.com/r-tmap/tmap/blob/39acf6cbe06a893487b08fb147494807274ab159/R/print_tmap.R#L150-L153) to determine the aspect ratio.

There doesn't seem to be any obvious way to avoid this; maybe worth posting [an issue](https://github.com/r-tmap/tmap/issues) (possibly related to/the same as [this one](https://github.com/r-tmap/tmap/issues/542) ?

Comment: Thanks @Ben Bolker, I asked if is the same issue as https://github.com/r-tmap/tmap/issues/542